# .htaccess redirect codeigniter subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

My website has that URL structure:

- http://mywebsite.com/blog
- http://mywebsite.com/signup
- etc.

and in CodeIgniter route file

```
$route['sign-up'] = 'members/signup';
$route['blog']    = 'blog/home';
```

I would like to have instead:

- http://blog.mywebsite.com
- http://signup.mywebsite.com

My hosts file is ok:

```
127.0.0.1       www.mywebsite.com
127.0.0.1       mywebsite.com
127.0.0.1       blog.mywebsite.com
127.0.0.1       signup.mywebsite.com
```

Im trying many tips with RewriteCond and RewriteRule but I don't find the good match...

Thank's!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could easily "hack" your `config/route.php` file that way without even modifying your .htaccess :

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'blog.mywebsite.com') {
    $route['default_controller'] = 'blog/home';
    // Other routes to your blog
} elseif ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'signup.mywebsite.com') {
    $route['default_controller']    = 'members/signup';
    // Other routes for your signup
}
```

Comment: Hello, when i'm accessing to 'blog.mywebsite.com' i'm redirecting to the root server path such as localhost.

my .htaccess:

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|src|upload|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Your htaccess seems ok, but what do you mean by redirected. Does the server respond 302 Redirect or 301 Redirect ?

Comment: Hello MaxiWheat.
I don't know about many redirects styles, I would like to see the subdomain in the navbar but call the "default" route, [URL]/blog for example.

Comment: Nop, I want what I wrote on the main post, nothing more, nothing less.
I just gave you my .htaccess content to show you that you have suggested does not work.
I'm totally noob in htaccess file. However, I appreciate that you are trying to help me!

Comment: Ok... When you say you are redirected to localhost, does the URL in your browser change or does it stays what you typed?

Comment: Hummm I don't really understand with the information I have now, can you update your question to include your whole `route.php` as modified with my suggestions ?